# Minimum hardware requirements for ati eyefinity

Tags: linux, hardware-rec, eyefinity

I have a triple monitor setup running under an nvidia 9800GT and a quadro NVS 295 (pcie x1). I have things setup with xinerama so that I can use all three of my monitors like it was one big huge thing. So while this setup serves my purposes in many ways, there are also some annoyances:

1. xrandr doesn't work with xinerama
2. compositing doesn't work across two cards. So no compiz, and worse yet, no transparency.
3. fullscreen flash videos (youtube, hulu, etc.) don't work well at all.

I gather all of these issues stem from either xinerama or two video cards. So I'm thinking it may be time to upgrade to an ati card that can run an eyefinity setup.

I don't really do that much that puts much strain on my graphics card(s). I don't do a bunch of 3d stuff, in fact, most of what I do is in a terminal window or a web browser. Occasionally I do some GPGPU stuff, but not all that much.

So basically what I am trying to ask here is what kind of hardware is recommended for someone needing to power 3x1920x1200. Can the cheap radeon 5450 do the trick? Or should I look more towards the mid range cards like the 5770 or better?

Comment: If your monitors support DisplayPort, the FirePro 2460 is the best thing under the sun if you don't need any significant 3D performance.

Comment: What is the advantage of the FirePro line?  They seem to be really expensive when compared with the radeon series, and I don't see the performance difference.